# Create command to inline an image in a question?

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing

How to create a command to can insert the image in a line of text question? Since I have a lot of question types made True/False, Short Answer types, Multiple choice, etc. I want the command to be compatible or can be usable in each of the question types. How should i make it?
here is an example output to pdf for multiple choice:

[image: multiple choice]

I am currently using my created class based from the exam.cls help please.. thank you..

## Code

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{/home/kayla/Desktop/activity/}}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
\newcommand*{\Image}[1]{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=1cm,valign=m]{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question This look like a \Image{/home/kayla/Desktop/activity/ddd} but it    
 actually a \Image{/home/kayla/Desktop/activity/nest}
 dodmodod
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I made to place the image where my .tex file is placed. It always provides me an error. the

```
\newcommand*{\Image}[1]{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=!,valign=m]{#1}}%
```

is highlighted and it says

```
illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a
```

Comment: The solution below should work just as well with other classes -- nothing class specific in there.

Comment: To use the solution below you also need to add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to the preamble.

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to use [the `adjustbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox) to create a command the vertically aligns the image to middle of the line:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand*{\Image}[1]{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=!,valign=m]{#1}}%
\begin{document}
You can insert image here as
\Image{../images/EiffelWide}
and your text can continue after it
and spill onto the next line as well, so you can see how this works.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using exam.cls as the document class. I will use image in a question so it should be inside the `\begin{question}` & `\end{question}` tags. I tried the solution indicated above but it doesn't work. I am working in Ubuntu.

Comment: Saying "it does not work" does not relaly provide any information from which to diagnose the problem. It would be best if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem, and added it to you question.

Comment: Please create a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)  and add it to the question.

Comment: @Kayla: Perhaps your problem is that you are trying to go up the hierarchy. Try placing the image in the same place as the .tex file and see if that works. And, instead of describing the problem here in the comments, please see [this link as to what a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) is and add a MWE to the question.

Comment: i have edited the question! :)

Comment: I knew it, this solution has compiled successfully to texlive 2012!. Is there other possible solution for texlive 2009.. I will no longer update the version since this was only the given scope. (2009 only) i have no choice.

Comment: @Kayla: Well you could install the necessary packages and should work with 2009, but I do not have that version so can't test it.