# how to customize size of the image through arguments?

Tags: macros, graphics, width, height

Relating from this link, [Create command to inline an image in a question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98297/create-command-to-inline-an-image-in-a-question/98298?noredirect=1#comment211862_98298) is there a way so the image can be modified? Example `\Image[20][10]` where 20 is the height and 10 is the width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\ImportGraphics}[3]{\includegraphics[width=#1,height=#2]{#3}}
\begin{document}
\ImportGraphics{2cm}{4cm}{example-image}
\end{document}
```