# Make portions of document images so that text within is not-searchable

Tags: graphics, pdf, search

I would like to create a macro that converts its paramater into an image with the goal that the text within this macro is not found using the search feature built into *standard* PDF viewers.

Thus, searching the resulting document for "text" should produce only two matches and not four.  That is, any text in the highlighted box should ignored.

[image]

### Use-Case

I generate a *large* index of files and want to be able to search by the index entry only (and not the files names).

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{Node Style/.style={draw=red, thin, fill=yellow!50, anchor=base, inner sep=1pt,}}
\newcommand{\NonSearchableText}[2][]{%
    \tikz[baseline] \node [Node Style, #1] at (0,0) {#2};%
}%

\begin{document}
    \textbf{searchable text}
    \indent\NonSearchableText{non-searchable-text}

    \textbf{searchable text}
    \indent\NonSearchableText{non-searchable-text}
\end{document}
```

### Desired Ouput

The desired output can be created by using the first file here to create the image `non-searchable-text.png` which is included by the second.

1. File name: `non-searchable-text.tex`

   ```
   %%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line
   \documentclass[convert={density=300,outext=.png}]{standalone}
   \usepackage{tikz}

   \tikzset{Node Style/.style={draw=red, thin, fill=yellow!50, anchor=base, inner sep=1pt,}}
   \newcommand{\NonSearchableText}[2][]{%
       \tikz[baseline] \node [Node Style, #1] at (0,0) {#2};%
   }%

   \begin{document}
       \NonSearchableText{non-searchable-text}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Main File:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

   %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98297/create-command-to-inline-an-image-in-a-question
   \newcommand*{\Image}[1]{\includegraphics[valign=m]{#1}}%

   \begin{document}
       \textbf{searchable text}
       \indent\Image{non-searchable-text.png}

       \textbf{searchable text}
       \indent\Image{non-searchable-text.png}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: The problem is that a PDF based image (like TikZ) probably includes the text as text In the (vector graphics) image.  You would need to produce a rasterized image, which means using a graphics editor to convert.

Comment: You could precompute rasterized images of each letter.  There might be something useful in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm?s=2|33.7384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accsupp` package can do this.  The syntax is `\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=<searchable non-visualized text>}<non-searchable visualized text>\EndAccSupp{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,accsupp}

\tikzset{Node Style/.style={draw=red, thin, fill=yellow!50, anchor=base, inner sep=1pt,}}
\newcommand{\NonSearchableText}[2][]{%
    \tikz[baseline] \node [Node Style, #1] at (0,0) {%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=}#2.\EndAccSupp{}};%
}%

\begin{document}
    \textbf{searchable text}
    \indent\NonSearchableText{non-searchable-text}

    \textbf{searchable text}
    \indent\NonSearchableText{non-searchable-text}
\end{document}
```

The visual output is, as before

[image]

The searchable text of the document includes the following:

```
searchable text
searchable text
```

Comment: Wow!. Thats a lot simpler that the hack I had thought of. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, @PeterGrill. It is a useful package, allowing various clever applications, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use/233397#233397 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198516/is-there-such-thing-as-visual-only-whitespace/198519#198519