# Make words like naïve searchable via naive

Tags: pdf, unicode, bar, search, ascii

very short question about the handling of umlaut and other unicode characters. Is it possible to make them searchable via their ascii-"equivalent" (e.g. a for ä)? Or can that only be done by the pdf viewer(and its search engine)?

As in the example below, searching for "naive" only turns up the second, searching for Osaka only shows first.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
na\"ive
naive

Osaka
\=Osaka
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). A solution to may also help to solve [Make portions of document images so that text within is not-searchable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458404/4301).

Comment: You need at least `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. And then it depends a bit on the pdf viewer.

Comment: I've fiddled a little bit with `\usepackage{accsupp}` but it doesn't seem to provide a good solution either. Best possibility I found so far was using `pdf2text` and then `iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT`; although that returns `"a` for ä; if anyone knows how to just get from äöü -> aou etc. please let me know.

Comment: Even easier would be using ICUs uconv; I have trouble finding the exact command though. There is an online version to play with for anyone else who wants to convert input from different languages into ASCII: https://ssl.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit

Comment: After adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` If I try with Skim, it doesn't find “naïve”; Adobe Acrobat Reader does.